# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, raspberry-pi, palm

I'm trying to add some feature to this code that i got from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vipul-sharma20/gesture-opencv/master/gesture.py that i can capture any palm that i need and save it in folder, in first try its success,but the second is failure said:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "home/pi/Downloads/palmdetect.py", line 97, in<module>
    camera_capture = get_image()
File "home/pi/Downloads/palmdetect.py", line 11, in get_image
    crop_image = img[100:450, 100:450]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Code in `palmdetect.py`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def get_image():
    # read image
    ret, img = cap.read()
    # get hand data from the rectangle sub window on the screen
    cv2.rectangle(img, (300, 300), (100, 100), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    crop_img = img[100:300, 100:300]

    # convert to grayscale
    grey = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # applying gaussian blur
    value = (35, 35)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grey, value, 0)

    # thresholdin: Otsu's Binarization method
    _, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blurred, 127, 255,
                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    # show thresholded image
    cv2.imshow('Thresholded', thresh1)

    # check OpenCV version to avoid unpacking error
    (version, _, _) = cv2.__version__.split('.')

    if version == '3':
        image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
            thresh1.copy(),
            cv2.RETR_TREE,
            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
        )
    elif version == '2':
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(
            thresh1.copy(),
            cv2.RETR_TREE,
            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE
        )

    # find contour with max area
    cnt = max(contours, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x))

    # create bounding rectangle around the contour (can skip below two lines)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 0)

    # finding convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

    # drawing contours
    drawing = np.zeros(crop_img.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 0)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [hull], 0, (0, 0, 255), 0)

    # finding convex hull
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt, returnPoints=False)

    # finding convexity defects
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
    count_defects = 0
    cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    # applying Cosine Rule to find angle for all defects (between fingers)
    # with angle > 90 degrees and ignore defects
    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]

        start = tuple(cnt[s][0])
        end = tuple(cnt[e][0])
        far = tuple(cnt[f][0])

        # find length of all sides of triangle
        a = math.sqrt((end[0] - start[0])**2 + (end[1] - start[1])**2)
        b = math.sqrt((far[0] - start[0])**2 + (far[1] - start[1])**2)
        c = math.sqrt((end[0] - far[0])**2 + (end[1] - far[1])**2)

        # apply cosine rule here
        angle = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)) * 57

        # ignore angles > 90 and highlight rest with red dots
        if angle <= 90:
            count_defects += 1
            cv2.circle(crop_img, far, 1, [0, 0, 255], -1)
        # dist = cv2.pointPolygonTest(cnt,far,True)

        # draw a line from start to end i.e. the convex points (finger tips)
        # (can skip this part)
        cv2.line(crop_img, start, end, [0, 255,  0], 2)
        # cv2.circle(crop_img,far,5,[0,0,255],-1)

    # show appropriate images in windows
    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)
    all_img = np.hstack((drawing, crop_img))

    return img


temp = get_image()
print("Taking Image...")

camera_capture = get_image()
file = "home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg"

cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)

del(camera)
```

anyone knows how to fix it and the threshold windows doesn't appear

Comment: What's the stack trace? And have you debugged this at all yet?

Comment: Please give the entire error message.

Comment: Please share the full traceback

Comment: Did you Google your error message? You haven't included a traceback but you have a `None` somewhere

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, see [ask]

Comment: @lee-pai-long Tracebak this the full traceback 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "home/pi/Downloads/palmdetect.py", line 97, in<module>
  camera_capture = get_image()
 File "home/pi/Downloads/palmdetect.py", line 11, in get_image
  crop_image = img[100:450, 100:450]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "home/pi/Downloads/palmdetect.py", line 97, in<module>
  camera_capture = get_image()
 File "home/pi/Downloads/palmdetect.py", line 11, in get_image
  crop_image = img[100:450, 100:450]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that you can format the error message to be more readable.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes sir... i've already edit it, thanks for remind me

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) says that [`VideoCapture.read()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-read)

> combine VideoCapture::grab() and VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call

And VideoCapture::retrieve()

> decode and return the just grabbed frame. If no frames has been
>   grabbed (camera has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in
>   video file), the methods return false and the functions return NULL
>   pointer.

Translated in python you must expect `retvar` and `frame` where `frame` is not `None` only if `retval` is `True`.

In your code this line:

```
# read image
ret, img = cap.read()
```

Potentially give you img as None, so when you try to crop it here:

```
crop_img = img[100:300, 100:300]
```

You get your error:

> "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

You either need to test retval first:

```
retval, img = cap.read()
if retval:
    # get hand data from the rectangle sub window on the screen
    cv2.rectangle(img, (300, 300), (100, 100), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    crop_img = img[100:300, 100:300]
    ...
```

Or test for img not at None first:

```
# Since we don't use the return value let's just forget it
_, img = cap.read()
if img is not None:
    # get hand data from the rectangle sub window on the screen
    cv2.rectangle(img, (300, 300), (100, 100), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    crop_img = img[100:300, 100:300]
    ...
```

Then you'll have to handle the fact that your get_image function get no image (either return None or raise an Exception).

*Sidenote: Your code still have two issue, you have a line `all_img = np.hstack((drawing, crop_img))` at the  end of your function but you never use all_img. At the end of the module you do a `del(camera)` but camera is never defined. Finally if you have to share you code publicly please follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (Install [pylint](https://www.pylint.org) or just [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) in you editor or choice)*.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the "while" like this:
This way it will read all the frames and cut them

```
import cv2  
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('t8.mp4')

# x,y,h,w are the sizes you want to cut:
x=0 
y=0 
w=650 
h=750

success, frame = Image.read()

while success :
    success, frame = Image.read()
        
    if success: 
        cropeedIMAGE = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow('finger', cropeedIMAGE)
        
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`
to `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`
or `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(2)`
or `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(3)`
...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).